# Motivation for particular definition of contractible type

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

There is a mainstream definition of a contractible type and it goes like this: $\textrm{isContr} (A) = (x:A) \,\#\, (y:A) \to (x == y)$, where $\#$ means dependent pair (precedence and associativity same as $\to$) and $==$ is a path type.

Now, if I read this as "there is an x:A such that there's path between every y:A and x", then it sounds like path-connectedness, not contractibility.

The imho more intuitive definition, $\textrm{isContr} (A) = (x:A) \to (\textrm{loop}:x==x) \to (\textrm{loop} == \textrm{refl}\, x)$, was deemed impractical. **Edit:** By some text I don't recall the name of.

I ask why is it so? What makes the "canonical" definition define contractibility when it intuitively corresponds to path-connectedness? Why is it more convenient to use?

Explanation for both HoTT and/or CuTT are welcome.

PS: I'm not sure whether the "more intuitive" loop definition of contractibility requires dependent function (for all), or whether a dependent pair suffices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For contractibility defined as $\text{isContr}(A) :\equiv \Sigma_{a:A} \Pi_{x:A} (a=x)$,
(cf. page 124 of [the HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)), the intuitive idea is that every point $x$ is *the same point* as $a$.

The way you are reading the definition is common, and says:

"there is an $a$ such that for each $x$ there is a path from $a$ to $x$"

I completely agree, this sounds like path-connected-ness. *However* we get this reading by mixing our interpretations of types. Here we forget the topological data in the $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ types (by reducing them to mere quantifiers) but we *remember* the topological data in the identity type!

If you want to use the quantifier lingo, stick to it. Then the sentence says

"there is an $a$ such that for each $x$, $a=x$"

which DOES sound like contractibility.

Alternatively, if you want to use topological intuition, you have to remember what $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ types mean -- there's a naturality condition in how we pick our paths. With path-connected-ness we can pick each path separately, however we need to. However, because of naturality, we are saying there is some uniform way to find a path from any point $x$ to $a$ -- that's exactly what it means to have a deformation retract to $a$.

In this interpretation, $\text{isContr}(A)$ is the type of pairs $(a,r)$ where $a$ is a point in $A$ and $r$ is a deformation retract to $a$, which *also* sounds like a good definition for contractibility.

There's a very good discussion of exactly this mistake (which everyone makes, by the way) [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/03/homotopy_type_theory_ii.html), as well as good background reading motivating why the definitions are what they are.

---

If a blind appeal to naturality isn't satisfying, by the way, I encourage you to actually prove the associated theorem. It isn't very difficult, and it's what finally convinced me that $\text{isContr}$ was correct:

If $(a,r) : \text{isContr}(A)$, then $r$ is (judgementally) equal to the type $\text{const}_a \sim \text{id}_A$. That is, $r$ witnesses the constant function at $a$ is homotopic to the identity function on $A$, and so it is actually a deformation retract, as claimed.

---

Hope this helped ^_^

---

**Edit:**

I realize I've left out part of your question, so let me try to remedy that now.

Why *not* take $\text{intuitiveContr}(A) = \Pi_{x:A} \Pi_{\alpha : x=x} (\alpha = \text{refl}_x)$ as a definition? Leaving aside the fact that it admits the empty type as contractible (which is easily fixed), what bad can really come of it?

The more pressing reason to not take $\text{intuitiveContr}(A)$ as a definition is that it doesn't capture contractibility. Instead, it captures the notion of **Simply Connected** (cf. [this article](https://mathinsight.org/definition/simply_connected)).

$\text{intuitiveContr}$ insists that all loops can be contracted to refl, but it says nothing about higher homotopy. The 2-sphere, for instance, satisfies $\text{intuitiveContr}$, but is *not* contractible. Even though there is no 1-dimensional obstruction to contractibility (i.e. every loop contracts to a point), there *is* a 2-dimensional obstruction to contractibility (the sphere is not filled in with a ball). Unfortunately, $\text{intuitiveContr}(A)$ misses this.

Part of the magic of $\text{isContr}$ is that it avoids this problem. One can prove (using function extensionality) that $\text{isContr}(A) \to \text{isContr}(\text{isContr}(A))$, and using this we can inductively show that homotopy vanishes in all dimensions.

Said another way, it is an easy exercise to show that contractible types are equivalent to $\textbf{1}$, the singleton type (also on page 124 of the HoTT book), so it is the *right* definition.

Comment: A couple additions. 1) The loop definition given actually defines the empty space as contractible, because it's missing the inhabitation part. 2) In a similar vein to this answer, if we read the standard `isContr` like "path connected", isn't the alternate definition read as, "the loop space is path connected?" But e.g. the loop space of the sphere is path connected, right?

Comment: 3) Also, since the loop definition is the same as saying the loop space is contractible (via the standard notion), any HSet qualifies, because the loop space is a proposition with point `refl`. I expect a better definition involves _two_ points, but then the problem mentioned occurs that `refl` doesn't go between two arbitrary points, so you need additional complications to mediate between between the paths, or similar. But it will probably boil down to writing a more complicated type just to convince yourself not to read it the wrong way, even though you still could.

Comment: What do you mean by missing inhabitation? I've left the inhabitation requirement for the standard definition implicit as well.

Comment: Also, how is the loop space of a circle path-connected? I'm in fact just a high schooler and I know just some basic topology, abs. algebra, and category theory. But how do you connect a loop that winds two times around the circle to that which does so just once?

Comment: In the standard isContr, the $Σ$ provides a value of $A$, proving it's inhabited. But the loop version above doesn't require that any points exist. Also, I mean sphere as in the surface of a globe. You can shrink 1-dimensional loops on the surface of a sphere to a point, but it isn't contractible (because there is a non-trivial 2-dimensional sheet that can't be shrunk).

Comment: I think in more generality, the n-spheres are each something that looks contractible until you get up to dimension n (and the 0-sphere actually is defined to be contractible, I guess, according to a table on wikipedia). My topology is not too strong either, though, even though I've been studying things much longer. :)

Comment: Oh I see, I've just misread and was thinking of a circle instead of a sphere :) Then you're right, circles on a sphere are all contractible. Do you think the loop definition could be expanded so that it's equivalent to the "singleton" definition? I'm sure I've seen something similar to it...

Comment: I mean, you could use $Σ_{x:A}Π_{y:A}Σ_{p : x≡y}Π_{q:x≡y} p≡q$, but this is equivalent to the original. And you can keep expanding the type in this way, and all of them are equivalent, just more verbose.

Comment: By "there is some uniform way to find a path from any point $x$ to $a$", do you mean that the choice of path is continuous in the point $x$, or a different condition?

Comment: Exactly! cf. this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25965/655547